# Checkbox bind even if null (datatable control)

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

I need to bind my checkbox somewhere even if it's null so I won't get an error about invalid casting.

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("DeleteFlag", typeof(bool));
```

In ASP:

```
    <asp:CheckBox ID="MyCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("DeleteFlag") %>'
                    Enabled="False"/>
```

(If I remove this code, it works, but no checkbox visible ofc.)
Maybe instantiate it with a value set to it already (true , false)

Can anyone help please? Will reply in comment if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use bool.Parse().

```
   <asp:CheckBox ID="MyCheckBox" runat="server"
Checked='<%#bool.Parse(Eval("DeleteFlag").ToString())%>'
                        Enabled="False"/>
```

Or this is what you are looking for:

```
Checked='<%# Eval("DeleteFlag") == DBNull.Value ? false :  Eval("DeleteFlag") %>'
```