# Bind checkbox on DB initial null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, bind

I need to bind a checkBox but with this line of code,

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxRed" runat="server"  Checked='<%# Bind("red") %>'/>
```

because initially the value in the DB is null, I get an invalid cast. I therefore tried in this way:

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxRed" runat="server"  Checked='<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"red") is DBNull ?false:Eval("red")) %>'/>
```

This avoids the initial invalid cast but if I check the checkbox the value is not saved to the db.
Is there a way to avoid the initial invalid cast and get the checked/unchecked status saved into the db?

I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980312/checkbox-bind-even-if-null-datatable-control) answer but it does not bind the value.

Comment: Does it work if you change Eval("red") to Bind("red") in your second version? If not, maybe try to convert nulls to false in DataSource before binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxRed" runat="server"  Checked='<%# Boolean.Parse(Eval("IsActive").ToString()) ? true : false%>'/>
```